# How to use spring in Android Application?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, spring-android

I am trying to use `spring` in my `android app` as client of my `spring mvc REST` application. I think I have a problem to put correct `jars` in `classpath` of my android app. I put the image of jars in libs folder of my android app. I found many related question on SO. But none of them helped me. That is why i am asking here again.

[image]

Here is how I am calling my webservice referenced from [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/#_add_dependencies) :

```
@Override
protected SowResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
    System.out.println("URLLLL : "+URL);
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    SowResult result = rest.getForObject(URL, SowResult.class);
    return result;
}
```

And the exception I am getting:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.getJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:166)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.canRead(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:101)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:542)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:474)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
at com.inovarge.shoponway.resttasks.UserRestTask.doInBackground(UserRestTask.java:30)
at com.inovarge.shoponway.resttasks.UserRestTask.doInBackground(UserRestTask.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception indicates that you are missing a required Jackson dependency. First, I recommend using `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instead of the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` which you've configured:

```
rest.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

Next, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` depends on the [Jackson 2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) library for its functionality, which requires the following files be on your classpath:

- jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
- jackson-core-2.3.2.jar

You already have `jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar` in your `libs` folder, so you need to [download](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload) the other two jars.

Lastly, I highly recommend using a dependency management system like the Gradle plugin in Android's [New Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). It will handle downloading all the transitive dependencies for you instead of having to manually do that.

Comment: first thank you for your answer and I am sorry for responding you late . I exactly did what you said and these 3 jars are in my classpath. But I am getting this exception now: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering

Comment: it works well. It was my mistake. I was insistently using wrong jackson-core jar :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for following up.